# Help understanding a bit of Visualforce code

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

Could someone explain to me in plain English what this code could possibly be doing. I have been banging my head against the wall to figure out. Esp the CurrencyIso code bit. I am a newbie :)

```
"Obj.Price__c != Obj.Price_Discount__c">
 {{Obj.Price_Discount__c | currency:Obj.CurrencyIsoCode+" ":0}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really about AngularJS not Visualforce.

See the Angular [currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) documentation; the first argument (after the first `:`) is the currency symbol and the second argument (after the second `:`) is the number of decimal places.

`Obj` is a JavaScript object probably added by a Javascript controller and `CurrencyIsoCode` is a field of that object. Search the code base for where that field is setup.

The code is most likely displaying a price with the appropriate currency symbol e.g. `$`.

Answer (score 0):

> **ngShow** Is an Angular directive.
>   The **ngShow** directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.